# Is the Sodexo Meal Pass accepted in Italy and France?

Tags: france, italy, food-and-drink, payment-cards, restaurants

Is the Sodexo Meal Pass accepted in Italy and France?
If yes, how to find those list of restaurants online?

Comment: Here are two links for you: https://fr.sodexo.com/home.html, https://it.sodexo.com/home.html

Comment: Which country is your meal pass from? I can't find anything about meal pass on the french website (and I don't speak italian). Looking at the one from India and the Philippines for instance, it seems like this is limited to specific countries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although operating in 80 countries through employer benefits and rewards programs, use of the Sodexo card appears to be limited to the country in which it was issued, and where it has contracts with Merchant Partners.

Sodexo [Meal Pass](https://www.sodexobenefitsindia.com/users/) is valid at [affiliated 'eating joints or outlets’](https://outlets.sodexobenefitsindia.com/?_ga=2.146471159.23355619.1529249726-2126525281.1529249726) all of which are in India.

Sodexo Italy has [Pass Lunch](http://www.sodexo-benefits.it/aziende/pass-lunch), with [affiliates throughout the country](http://www.affiliatisodexo.com/?_ga=2.178936236.905559727.1529250898-1837579338.1529250898).

Sodexo France offers a [Commander Pass Restaurant](https://www.sodexoavantages.fr/) and the [restaurant finder listing are within France](https://www.sodexoavantages.fr/geolocalisation-cheque-restaurant/).